# Python Unit test for least common ancestor gives TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, treenode

When running the file it gives **TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**. I'm just learning unit test in python. Can't figure out why and what's the wrong with me?

file **lca.py**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

root = Node(1)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(3)
root.left.left = Node(4)
root.left.right = Node(5)

def least_common_ancestor(root=root, n1=1, n2=1):
    if root.value == n1 or root.value == n2:
        return root.value

    left = least_common_ancestor(root.left, n1, n2)
    right = least_common_ancestor(root.right, n1, n2)

    if left and right:
        return root.value

    if left:
        return left
    else:
        return right

least_common_ancestor = least_common_ancestor(root, node1, node2)
```

file **unittest.py**

```
import lca

class TaskTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_least_common_ancestor(self):
        result_1 = lca.least_common_ancestor(node1=1, node2=3)
        self.assertEqual(result_1, 3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**errors what i'm getting when running the unit_test.py:**

```
..E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_least_common_ancestor (__main__.TaskTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/learn_python/unit_test.py", line 5, in test_least_common_ancestor
    result_1 = lca.least_common_ancestor(node1=1, node2=3)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: Are those `root = Node(1)` etc. lines supposed to be inside your class or after it? You're not going to be able to call `Node(1)`, `Node(2)` etc. from inside the definition of the `Node` class because the class doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Check your code. After fixing the indentation this code runs with no errors. If you still get errors, post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: @DeepSpace and khelwood : Modified the code with actual indentation. Actually i'm getting errors running unittest file. but others working fine.

Comment: it still doesn't make sense. You show us `unittest.py` which supposedly has 8 lines, but the stacktrace you provided comes from `unit_test.py` (note underscore) which has at least 63 lines. Either way, from the error it appears that you assigned `lca.lca` with an integer somewhere in the 62 lines above

Comment: @DeepSpace : it's a typo mistake. There is some others python file testing code. I just reduced the code written for only lca.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line 
**least_common_ancestor = least_common_ancestor(root, node1, node2)**. This variable contains integer value and conflicted with method name. Try renaming the variable.
Another changes you must need to pass root node as first parameter. Try **result_1=lca.least_common_ancestor(lca.root, 1, 3)**. Enjoy coding.